# How to set multiple address(smart contracts) to another smart contract's owner via Gnosis Safe?

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, gnosis-safe

How can I set multiple addresses to an ERC20 token's owner?

Here is what i want to do, i wrote an ERC20 token and it's interface, and using Openzeppelin's Ownable lib to set an function can only call by the owner. But i need to call this function in another contract. I find Gnosis Safe can set multiple owner to an contract, but after searching for the docs, i donot get the answer.

My ERC20 token:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

import "./IMyToken.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable, IMyToken {
  constructor() ERC20("My ERC20 Token", "MYT") {}
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount)
    external
    override
    onlyOwner
  {
    _mint(_to, _amount);
  }
```

My IMyToken.sol:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

interface IMyToken is IERC20 {
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) external;
}
```

Another contract:

```
import "./IMyToken.sol";

contract MyContract {

  IMyToken public immutable myToken;
  
  constructor(address _myToken) {
    myToken = IMyToken(_myToken);
  }

  function DistributeMyToken(address _to, uint256 _amount) external nonReentrant {
    myToken.mint(_to, _amount);
  }
```

When i call DistributeMyToken, it will throw an not ownable error. But i don't want to transfer MyToken's ownership to MyContract, There are some other contract should call the function, how can i solve it with Gnosis Safe?

Please help, thanks.

Comment: if you limited token minting only to the owner of the token contract and want to use the Safe with it, then you should set the Safe as an owner of the token contract

Comment: Is there any guides or reference? How can i set the Safe as an owner of the token contract? It that just transfer the token contract's ownership to the Safe address.

Comment: yes, exactly that.

Comment: thanks, i'm trying, but got stuck with some other issues.